# Drupal 8 problem to list taxonomy word of unpublished content in a view

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I made a view for the backend. Something like we know from backend for listing content. I want to list the taxonomy term for all content. No matter whether content is published or not. But the view only shows content, if content is published. What do I have do to show taxonomy terms for unpublished content?
[image: example for the output of my view]

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but it's an issue I've been struggling with, too, so I thought I'd post an answer. Turns out there's a known issue (feature request, actually) with the taxonomy module going back to D7. You can get all the details at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/962664.

There are patches there for 8.2, 8.3 and 8.4 that might solve your problem until the fix/feature makes into a stable release.